# How can I profile Python functions line-by-line in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, profiling, python-2.5, shared-libraries

I'd like to use line_profiler to profile a single large method line by line in my GoogleAppEngine application.

Unfortunately GAE doesn't seem to let you import .so libraries, even on a local dev server.

How could I go about achieving my goal?
I'd be happy to use a python-only solution, if there's one out there, or take suggestions as to how to write my own.

Comment: Can you [*try this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771)?

Comment: The stdlib cProfile module works.  See e.g. http://code.google.com/p/rietveld/source/browse/main.py#74

Comment: Do you need to profile this method in the development server or in production?

Answer (score 0):

Use [gae_mini_profiler](https://github.com/kamens/gae_mini_profiler).

It can either keep track of all function calls and their timings (instrumented) or can periodically examine the call stack to figure out in which functions time is being spent during a request (sampling).  You can see an example of it in action here - http://mini-profiler.appspot.com/